# regex matches string despite negative lookahead

Tags: javascript, python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to match the first 2 words in a string, except when the second one is "feat", then I just want to match the first word.

My plan:
`(\w+(?: \w+))(?!feat)`
does not work. "feat" gets matched everytime. I tried variations of the same, but to no avail.

Here's an example string: "Technotronic feat Ya Kid K"

Thank  you for your help!

Edit:

this is the string where it flips:
"Technotronic feat Ya Kid K"

this is the code that should cut the string:

```
pattern = re.compile("^\w+(?: (?!feat\b)\w+)?")

def cut(string):
    str = pattern.search(string).group(0)

    return str
```

Comment: `\w+(?: (?!feat\b)\w+)?` or `\w+(?:\s+(?!feat\b)\w+)?`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SGlu7H/1).

Comment: this finally works, thank you - did not know you have to insert it into the non-capturing group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
\w+(?: (?!feat\b)\w+)?
\w+(?:\s+(?!feat\b)\w+)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SGlu7H/1).

The point is that you need to restrict what the second `\w+` matches *right before* the `\w+` (as lookaheads match the text immediately after the current position), and to allow matching words *starting with* `feat`, you need to use a word boundary after `feat` in the lookahead.

*Regex details*:

- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?:\s+(?!feat\b)\w+)?` - an optional non-capturing group:

  - `\s+` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(?!feat\b)` - immediately to the right, there cannot be a whole word `feat`  (so, the subsequent `\w+` won't match `feat` but will match `feature`)
- `\w+`  - one or more word chars.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/kcH6Xz):

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"^\w+(?: (?!feat\b)\w+)?")

def cut(text):
    m = pattern.search(text)
    if m:
        return m.group(0)
    return string

print(cut("Technotronic feat Ya Kid K"))    # => Technotronic
print(cut("Technotronic feature Ya Kid K")) # => Technotronic feature
```

Comment: I understand. In theory and on regex101 it works. In my code, it won't. This is not the first time I'm working with regex so I know how to use it. Do you have any idea what could lead to this expression not working?

Comment: @poorlydisguised It works in practice, too. If you share the code, I will show. I did not post the code as you did not share yours. Without seeing your code, it is not clear what is wrong.

Comment: @poorlydisguised You forgot to use the `r` prefix before the string literal to make it raw. `pattern = re.compile(r"^\w+(?: (?!feat\b)\w+)?")`

Comment: @poorlydisguised I suggest checking for a match first, and only get the `.group(0)` when there is a match. Else, return the whole input string. Or do whatever you expect. Also, `str` is a built-in, it is not recommended to name variables as built-ins.